# Why does my rounding function return different results for different versions?

Tags: erlang

Please tell me why the function gives different results on different versions.

```
vsn 19.1
list_to_float(float_to_list(615.4896 / 100, [{decimals, 2}])).
6.16


vsn 24.2
list_to_float(float_to_list(615.4896 / 100, [{decimals, 2}])).

6.15
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be [this change](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/1684), released in [Erts 9.3](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/notes.html#erts-9.3) as part of Erlang/OTP 20.3:

> Fixed bug in `float_to_list/2` and `float_to_binary/2` with option decimals that caused a faulty rounding up of the last decimal digit for about 6% of floats with a fraction part.
>
> For example, `float_to_list(0.145, [{decimals,1}])` returned "0.2" instead of "0.1".
>
> Own Id: OTP-14890